# How to position axes from top of the figure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

When I issue the following command

```
>> figure; axes('Units','pixels','Position',[0,0,100,100])
```

I get small 100x100 axes object at the left bottom corner of a figure.

The size of the axes remains constant and it also remains docked to the same corner if figure resize.

How to do the same with upper left corner?

Comment: use the resize callback function of the figure.

Comment: is this the only option?

Comment: you want part of your `'Position'` to be `'normalized'` (relative location of axes) while keeping other part of `'Position'` to be `'pixels'` (the width and height)... I can't think of another method of achieving that... But there are other people around that might surprise me!

Comment: No no, I want all components to be pixels. Just so that origin be at another place.

Comment: if you want axes to be "docked" to **upper** left corner, even after figure resize, than the lower left corner of your axes (two first elements of `'Position'`) are `'normalized'` w.r.t figure size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the origin to the upper left corner you can set the attributes `xaxislocation` to `top` and `yaxislocation` to `left`. Further you can mention that y coords should increase from top to bottom by setting `ydir` to `reverse`.

To make sure the size of the axes is maintained set attribute `ActivePositionProperty` to `Position`.

So at the end your command will look something like:

```
figure;axes('Units','pixels','Position', [10,200,100,100],'xaxislocation','top','yaxislocation','left','ydir','reverse','ActivePositionProperty','Position')
```

Note that in the figure obtained origin is at the upper left corner of the axes **not** that of the window.